# custom emails on VSTS build pass and fail

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build definition in VSTS. I want to shoot out a mail to participants in following two scenarios

1. if build fails, mail with subject "build failed" and body
   containing which step in definition failed and its explanation.
2. if build succeed, Build success mail

Build fail scenarios may include,

1. stylecop errors,
2. Code analysis error,
3. test fails,
4. codecoverage results,
5. or simply build error.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. I cannot think of anything out of the box then, you may be able to query the build status via the API (I can't see any variables with it in) and then feed that into the body of a third party email sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared a custom power-shell script to get status of all the tasks in build definition.
And now i am using these result to prepare a custom email body and sending out this mail.

This script gets the status from Apis available in VSTS.

Thank you all for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

There is the feature of sending email to corresponding users when build complete or fail, but you can’t custom the email body (1. Go to admin page of your team project 2. Select Notification).

You can send the email in a custom build extension when build complete. There is the sample of build result: [build-results-enhancer](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer) (The send mail logical can be in _initBuildStatus function in status.ts)

More information about extension for VSTS, you can refer to: [Create your first extension for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node)

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using specialized tools like [CatLight build monitor for VSTS](https://catlight.io). It provides a convenient workflow to notify the team about the broken builds and shows who is investigating the build right now.

Specifically, it will show notifications on the desktop about build successes and failures.
[image: CatLight build notification]

It does not show the reason for the build failure right away, but you can click on the build on the dashboard, and it will open a VSTS page with detailed build results.

[image: CatLight team build dashboard screen]